# Ajax request not pulling up jQuery dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-dialog

Please review this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/aEwUF/)**...

This is a jQuery UI dialog box utilizing an ajax request to pull up the content. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, but nothing's popping up other than the blank dialog.

**HTML...**

```
<div id="#griffin"></div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="ajax/ajax-bj.html" class="griffin-style all-about-bj" id="all-about-bj"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript...**

```
$(function() {
    $("#griffin").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 950,
        height: 'auto',
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "I have Read and Understand": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
        $(".griffin-style").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#griffin").html("");
            $("#griffin").dialog("option", "title", "Loading...").dialog("open");
            $("#griffin").load(this.href, function() {
                $(this).dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h1").text());
                $(this).find("h1").remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give the commands under `buttons` parameter.

**http://jsfiddle.net/aEwUF/4/**

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#griffin" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:150,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "I have read and understand the terms": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          $("p").html("You have accepted the terms");
          //write ajax requests in here..
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: However, where would I place the href? I'm trying to call another page on the root.

Comment: I needed it to be styled the same way my original one was. Here's the actual page where it's located. I placed the ajax request where you said to, but it's still not coming up. The page is [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/bj/Template2.html). Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a jQuery UI dialog **open** function

**http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open**

you will have to run this locally or on the same server since the jsfiddle cant pull your external file due to same origin policy

**http://jsfiddle.net/aEwUF/7/**

```
$(function() {
    $("#griffin").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 950,
        height: 'auto',
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "I have Read and Understand": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
                    // add this
        open:function(event,ui){
                $("#griffin").html("");
                $("#griffin").load($(".griffin-style").attr("href"), function() {
                $("#griffin").dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h1").text());
                $(".griffin-style").find("h1").remove();
            }); 
        }
    });


     $(".griffin-style").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#griffin").html("");
                $("#griffin").dialog("option", "title", "Loading...").dialog("open");
                $("#griffin").load(this.href, function() {
                    $("#griffin").dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h1").text());
                    $(this).find("h1").remove();
                });
    }); 

 });
```

Comment: In my page, it's being pulled as `"ajax/ajax-request.html"`. I did it that way in the fiddle just as an example.

Comment: do you have more of your HTML from above.. like where **#griffin** is?

Comment: sorry about that. When i posed this question, that portion didn't come through on the code. I've edited it above.

Comment: Thoughts on this Jonathan?

Comment: @webfrogs just updated answer for you to use open method on jQuery ui dialog - http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open -